# Can webview read files which outside assets folder?

Tags: android

I am new to android. Now I am using webview to run some JS and HTML. I know I can link some files inside assets folder. But how about some files outside this folder. For example, "data/data/packagename/files/index.js". Is that available to read this file? How can I use it?
My program:
I use java to retrieve some data (JSON type) from server by TCP. And then I write them into a JSON file which under "data/data/packagename/files". Then I use jQuery ajax function to ready them and use the data to draw line chart.
Any good solutions how to improve it? Because I am really bad in java, I use a lot of JS instead. Another thing is I can't find a free and handy line chart library. (I can find them in JS. :( )

Answer (score -2):

You can use PhoneGap to access any file resources outside the Assets folder